# Inducing hallucinations to attract prey

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, creature-design

Rock snails are giant slug like creatures living in the forest and underwater, they are not mobile in adulthood and their shell resembles a giant rock.

They grow up to being  8 meters tall and they are so heavy they can't move and let themselves become the environment by getting covered in grass and bushes or algae and corals.

They attract prey to eat them by causing hallucinations, very specific hallucinations.

A bird will see and hear another bird or storm of birds eating something on the ground or maybe calling them, a person might see a familiar or a friend and a dog might see it's owner or another dog friend or it's own puppies.

In a way the giant snail uses the visual and auditive memories of an animal to attract it and then eat it alive.

What substance or mechanism can be used to force hallucinations based on actual memories that attract you towards them and don't scare or terrorize you? I had many hallucinations as a kid and knowing they were hallucinations, I couldn't help but being terrified, the difference being that none of the hallucinations I ever had where related to real existing things. But I guess if I casually saw my cousin calling me  while walking in a forest then "oh that guy wants to devour me alive" wouldn't be the first thing on my mind.

Comment: The egg piece is a distraction and not related to the main question.  I recommend that be deleted from this and  (if desired) asked as a separate question.

Comment: It's a little outside the question, but if your organism can do this, why doesn't it simply stimulate the prey pleasure centers, and the closer the prey gets, the more pleasure it feels. Turn it off to avoid predation, or stimulate pain/fear responses. If you want, hallucinations could be a side-effect of this.

Comment: The Despair Squid from Red Dwarf springs to mind. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_Reality_(Red_Dwarf))

Comment: Is it actually necessary that the effect be positive and attractive to every potential target?  If some animals/people are frightened, others are attracted, and many are only disoriented, the slug still gets fed sometimes.  It only needs to work often enough, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any hallucinogenic substance will trigger hallucinations which are based on the subjects own memories, anxieties and thoughts. The content of your trip is entirely your own creation.

Humans have an unparalleled ability to rationalise their choices (technically, choice-supportive bias).

Your snails secrete a substance or mixture with two actions: a hallucinogen, and one which generates a pull towards the source (like, say, an opiate which encourages the inhaler to keep getting closer to get stronger doses).  The hallucinogen causes the brain to generate suitable fantasies about why moving in one particular direction makes them feel happy, whether they are seeing an image of their first love, their mothr, or a particularly enticing pizzas

Answer (score 1):

**Transcranial magnetic stimulation.**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcranial_magnetic_stimulation#Physics

> TMS uses electromagnetic induction to generate an electric current
>   across the scalp and skull.[19][20] A plastic-enclosed coil of wire is
>   held next to the skull and when activated, produces a magnetic field
>   oriented orthogonal to the plane of the coil. The magnetic field can
>   then be directed to induce an inverted electric current in the brain
>   that activates nearby nerve cells in a manner similar to a current
>   applied superficially at the cortical surface.[21]

Your slug needs to reach invisibly through the air and create activity in the brains of its victims.  This is basically possible - one can produce brain activity using magnetic fields.

It will be difficult to aim these fields for the slug - the targets are at a distance and in motion.  If the stimulation field hits another part of the brain it will do different things.

I like the idea that the victims align themselves on purpose.  The victim hits the field and something weird starts happening to it.  The victim holds still, trying to figure it out, changing position - and then suddenly it realizes that there is something that it really needs to check out and it goes to the slug.

I also find more plausible the idea that the slug's abilities are tuned to its common prey organism.  On organisms that are more distantly related it might work less well, or have unpredictable effects.  Or maybe work even better.

---

the egg thing is peripheral to the main question and should be a separate question I think.

Comment: TMS  won't work. Positive memories aren't stored in places different from unpleasant memories. Second, I doubt the brain memory works like a computer storage, each "movie" in its own "file", its likely that two memories will share a group of neurons and be "located" in different strengths of the synapses. To compound the problem, "negative memories" are likely to be more frequent and stored in more details: after all, the survival of an individual depends more on the capability to avoid dangers than the capacity to remember... ummm... college parties. A huge problem with selectivity for TMS.